# How to disable/hide controls in a html page to some users

Tags: php, html

I am creating a small MIS with html and php with mysql database and there is a login function for the users and they have different user Levels.For example the manger's user level is 1. I want to create user grants for the system by disabling some controls such as buttons and tabs based on the user level. For example how can I disable this, for a user who has a user  level of 1.

```
                          <li>
                          <a href="SearchProduct.php">Search</a>
                        </li>
```

Comment: in this case, you can get the 'level' variable from your database and use `if` statements for those buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say for example your user is logged and you have his level saved in `$_SESSION['level']` or in $data['level'] representing the row fetched from your database. In your PHP you could simply do

```
<?php
    if ($level > 1) // Only for users above lvl 1 (at least lvl 2)
    {
        echo '<li>
                  <a href="SearchProduct.php">Search</a>
              </li>
    }
?>
```

Now your search bar is only visible to users above level 1. Make sure you replace the `$level` variable by the actual level of the currently logged user (either from `$_SESSION['level']` or from the result of a query)

Comment: Thank you @Ki Jey.It was big help